# IPS4 php get the id of current member

Tags: php, ipb

I want to block some peoples from ftp to acces modules via acp, like THEMES. I tried to block inside of 'function' eg 'public function resourceForm()' from 'applications/core/modules/admin/customization/themes.php' with :

```
    if( \IPS\Member::load( $this->member->member_id, 'member_id' ) == 1 )
    {
        return \IPS\Output::i()->output = "THIS SECTION IS LOCKED FOR YOU";
    }
```

but is not working..